# I am looking to print a simplified gmap macro builder

Tags: theming, google-maps, javascript

[image: mockup]

I am looking to print a simplified gmap macro builder in a page so users can submit maps on pages.

I am having difficulties printing any of the gmap macro. Ultimately I would like to print the simplified form into a modal but any help towards that would be appreciated.

Has anyone programmatically printed a gmap macro builder into a page?

Thank you for your help

This is what I have started for my code. I am stuck as where to go from here though. I have just pulled pieces that I believe relevant.

```
<?php
// Implementation of hook_menu()

function gmap_macro_builder_menu() {
 $items['map/macro'] = array(
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 'title' => 'Build a GMap macro',
 'access arguments' => array('create gmap macro'),
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('gmap_macro_builder_form'),
);
return $items;
}

//Simplified gmap macro builder form

function gmap_macro_builder_form($form, &$form_state, $settings = array(), $hide = array()) {
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'gmap');

$form['macroform'] = array(
 '#type' => 'fieldset', 
 '#title' => t('Gmap Macro Creation'), 
 '#theme' => 'gmap_macro',
);

$form['macroform']['mapdiv'] = array(
 '#type' => 'gmap', 
 '#map' => 'macro_map', 
 '#settings' => array_merge(array(
  'points' => array(), 
  'pointsOverlays' => array(), 
  'behavior' => array(
    'dynmarkers' => TRUE,
  ),
 ), $settings),
);

$defaults = array_merge(gmap_defaults(), $settings);
gmap_widget_setup($form['macroform']['zoom'], 'zoom', 'macro_map');

$form['macroform']['macro'] = array(
 '#type' => 'gmap_macrotext', 
 '#map' => 'macro_map', 
 '#default_value' => '', 
 '#title' => t('Macro text'),
);

foreach ($hide as $field => $mode) {
 if (isset($form['macroform'][$field])) {
  if ($mode == 1) {
    $form['macroform'][$field]['#type'] = 'hidden';
    $form['macroform'][$field]['#value'] = $form['macroform'][$field]['#default_value'];
  }
  elseif ($mode == 2) {
    $form['macroform'][$field]['#prefix'] = '<div style="display: none;">';
    $form['macroform'][$field]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
  }
 }
}

return $form;
}

?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? show code if you used code? explain why and where it doesn't work, and what you expect (in detail) it to accomplish. use screenshots if that helps

Comment: I have added a picture of a firebug mockup. I am looking to just have the map and the macro text output. I have tried to pull parts from the gmap_macro_builder_form, admittedly I am pretty new to Drupal and both php. I have embedded the entire thing into my page and pulled out the unnecessary parts, although I am not certain if I should be putting the code directly into the node.tpl.php or the template.php or make my own module

Comment: You're on the right track looking at gmap_macro_builder_form(). It shouldn't go in your theme it should go in a custom module. It's functionality, not styling and I assume if you ever wanted to change your theme you would want to keep this functionality. Either make a custom block or a custom page (menu callback, like the gmap macro module does). - My bed time limits me from posting a proper answer right now sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the direction. Not a problem, any help towards this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the map and textform for the macro built. I am stuck on figuring out how gmap prints out the macro string. When I check the textarea in firebug the string is not even stored in there. Am I missing some ajax or js script? I have added macro.js and macrobuilder.js

Comment: @rooby, sorry to bother you. I have everything working except for the textfield that updates with the current macro output. I cannot for the life of me figure that out (I have tried variously for the past month). I believe it is tied to an issue with the macro.js or macrobuilder.js (likely macro.js) not updating the field. When I move the map with my mouse the addressfield turns from empty to "enter an address", so it is not engaged until after the event. I am stumped.